# How to share mongo schema between nodejs and C

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a nodejs server that uses Mongo to store information.  I want to write some C code that will read and write this same information, which means that I need to share the schema between them.

Is there a mechanism to do that, or do I need to write a .h file that duplicates the information that is in my javascript?  If I do need to create duplicate information, are there any tools in place to keep them in sync or do I need to do it manually?  (This seems like something that is easy to do the first time, but as the schema changes it's going to be real easy for differences to creep in and go unnoticed until they cause problems).

Comment: By *"template"* I assume you mean schema? Which leads me to question why you would choose a *schemaless* database like MongoDB when your use-case clearly needs enforced schemas offered by databases like PostgreSQL or MySQL. These databases would error and refuse to process any queries that doesn't follow the schema while MongoDB would happily mutate the data and structure, possibly deleting/overwriting/corrupting parts of your data.

Comment: Yes, sorry, "schema."  (As you've likely guessed, I'm not a database person).  I decided on Mongo because almost all my code is Javascript and it interfaces to Javascript naturally, and the mongoose package has fully-debugged async interfaces to it.  PostreSQL would have been harder to wedge in.  (But yes, I very much miss the strong typing PostgreSQL gives you.  And C for that matter--I loathe casts in C, so Javascript is driving me up the wall in that respect).

Comment: Including Mongoose in your project is a strong indication that you're looking for a database that supports schemas, as that's essentially what Mongoose does; adding schemas on the application layer to a *schemaless* database. If you're looking for `async/await` support, it's not that hard to wrap callback-style APIs in a Promise, there's even an internal function offered by Node from the `utils` package that does this, see [`utils.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original). Alternatively there's ORMs like [TypeORM](http://typeorm.io/#/) which already does this.